# pointer aritmetic changes depending on output?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have these two almost identical bits of c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 2;
    int d = 3;
    int *p = &a;
    cout << &c << endl;
    cout << *(p+1);
}
```

with the output:

0x7ffd7b16998c

2

and

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 2;
    int d = 3;
    int *p = &a;
    cout << &d << endl;
    cout << *(p+1);
}
```

which produces the output:

0x7ffdb7ea105c

3

Why does the value of *(p+1) depend on what I output beforehand?
If I delete the line

```
cout << &c << endl;
```

completely i get the expected 1 as an output.

What on earth is happening?

Comment: Both of these are invoking *undefined behavior*, so you can't expect anything (or everything)

Comment: Okay i was just playing around with this. it is producing this behaviour reliably thats why i was surprised.

Comment: thanks for the link @usr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is *undefined behavior*.

When you obtain a pointer to an `int`, you are allowed to use the value of that pointer alone; pointer arithmetic is meaningless.

In order for `p+1` to produce an address that you can dereference, `p` must point to an array element other than its last element. In all other situations, reading `*(p+1)` is undefined.

Standards aside, the CPU must be taking that value from *some* place. You assume that the place must be the address of `b`, which is declared immediately after `a`. However, C++ makes no guarantees about location of local variables in memory relative to each other. It appears that the compiler reorders your variables, producing an output that you did not expect (and it's undefined anyway).

Comment: It is undefined but reliably reproduces the same undefined behaviour, man that is horrible^^ if you are learning this stuff... as I am trying at the moment..

Comment: @pindakaas I agree, the decision to leave some behavior undefined in a high-level programming language is quite horrible. A great deal of programs appear to be working fine on one standard-compliant platform, only to fail miserably when ported to a different standard-compliant platform. You can find bugs like this using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), but it is a very hard process.

Answer (score 1):

`*(p+1)` accesses memory **after** `a` so it's *Undefined Behaviour*.

Propably you intended `(*p)+1` to increase `a` by 1?

Comment: What do you mean by UB? Why would i need (*p)+1? this will always give the value of a+1 right?

Comment: @pindakaas I *suggested* `(*p)+1` because you haven't stated what *exactly* you want to happen. UB is happening because you access memory you shouldn't, because `*(p+1)` is adress of memory *after* `a` - it is similar to access array out of bounds. And when UB is happening *literally anything* can happen (there could be -371 in output for example)

Comment: Okay. coming from python this stuff is hard to stomach.